# How to know complete URL with querystring?

Tags: html, url, post, get

I am running a web application on firefox. When I click on the button it redirects to some page and processes query string. The query string parameters are hidden in the url.

Please let me know if there are any tools which can be used to identify the querystring parameters and to generate a complete url.

e.g.

Base URL - http://something.com/someAction

When I click on a button it redirects to "http://something.com/newAction

It hides the query string parameters.

How can I retrieve an entire url as - http://something.com/newAction?xxx=xxx&yy=yy&zz=zz

?

Comment: It is not possible to hide query string parameters in the url. What leads you to believe that is the case? Maybe it is a quick redirect?

Comment: Are you asking how your server side program (what language?) can get to query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

No. If the query string parameters are hidden, it is probably a POST request. To make the query string visible in URL, use GET request.

Please understand the difference of GET and POST request.

**Clarification:** POST request can have both query string as well as POST fields ( hidden query string you suggested )

Comment: You can have query parameters even on a POST request.

Comment: Yes, but in OP's case, it seems POST request is the case.